# Linux Screen command passed to wrong screen

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen

I have two screen session(eg: A & B ) for GSM modem, However, I am facing a problem where I sent AT command`screen -S A -X stuff 'AT\r'` to both screens(same port) but I have no idea why the command that was supposed to appear in A did not appear but showed both outputs(A&B) in B basically means it sent to the wrong screen session.

Comment: Sorry, what happened? Your description isn't very clear.

Comment: just when I send the AT command to both screen A & B (same port) screen A's output appeared at screen B and screen A shows nothing.

Comment: `AT` is not a `screen` command. Do you mean you *typed* `AT` in one session and something appeared in the other? Was the "something" `AT` (i.e. the wrong terminal echoed what you typed) or the response? or both?

Comment: aplogize for the misleading, should be ```screen -S A -X stuff 'AT\r'``` and yes you are right the ```AT``` command echoed in the wrong screen session

Comment: What program is running in both sessions? I have no experience with this at all but I can make some guesses. A serial line behaves like two fifos (one in, one out), it has no concept of separate connections. If the two programs write to and read from the same serial line then it's normal a random one of them gets a short response, no matter who triggered it. Long responses may get fragmented and different fragments will get to different recipients. If the echo is remote (as opposed to local echo) then `AT` you saw was a part of the response. Not an answer because I'm only guessing.

Comment: I was using php script to send the command to the detached screen

Comment: That doesn't matter. What @KamilMaciorowski pointed out is probably the reason. If both session use the same physical device over a serial connection it's already lucky that it's working and as he describes you might get output in either session.